# Chrome Flash Player: Couldn't load plugin

Tags: google-chrome, flash

One of my primary browsers has been Chrome, which did the job for me. Up until recently Flash Player worked fine until I had to manually enable Flash for every page. The last time Flash worked it asked me to execute Flash *only once*, I didn't expect it to block Flash completely from that point.

There are [multiple](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-chrome.html), [sources](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/108086?hl=en), [of](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enable-system-flash-player-google-chrome.html), [instructions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en) about enabling Flash (or similair plugins) but none of them seemed to work for me. I've enabled Flash Player in the Plugins-settings from Chrome but that didn't change a thing, the only result I get when I see something in Flash: "Couldn't load plugin".

Is there something I'm missing about enabling Flash in Chrome or should I start scouting for another browser? I rely on Flash for my job so I currently don't have another option.

Comment: have you tried chrome update? there are some new restriction added for flash recently

Comment: Great question; My version is 43.0.2357.124 m, while the latest version should be 43.0.2357.134. Unfortunately I can't run the updater right now.

Comment: I think is the update problem, i have heard about this during the past week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with comments.

Update your browser because flash encountered a big vulnerability, then they blocked to use it until adobe won't release a new ersion. If you update your chrome you will get the newest flash, and it will work again. (I had the problem some days ago too)

Comment: I had to wait for the IT department to update Chrome on my pc, but the update fixed the problem.